# Angular Project, Disable Add Icon, During Saving A New Object/Data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, disable

On top of my table that includes/shows a list of specific object, I put an add button, but actually it is not a button it is something like this, mixed of span, a and icon

```
    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
      <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
        <a class="text-success" (click)="add()">
          <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
        </a>
      </span>
.
.
.
    </div>
```

So, when the add icon is hit, the new empty row is created at the end of the table to add/enter the new object data, during this time, from creating new row to hit the save button, I would like the add button be disabled, but I could not disable this icon.

Note I have already had this button in my login form and it works properly,

```
 <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-signin">Sign In</button>
```

this login button will becoming disable during the credential check.
but I don't know how I can deal with this add icon

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf`. I'm not sure whether it will work on the `<mdb-icon>` tag or the even the `<a>` anchor tag so maybe something like this:

```
      <span *ngIf="someCondition" class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
        <a class="text-success" (click)="add()">
          <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
        </a>
      </span>

      <span *ngIf="!someCondition" class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
        <!-- whatever HTML you want to render instead, or nothing -->
      </span>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, but usually *ngIf does not show the element at all and it would be cause some changes in layout. I want just same layout but disable the add Icon to trigger any function. Anyway I will try your solution. Thanks @Ben Hulan.

Comment: Right. So in my sample code I have two `<span>` blocks. The first one has `*ngIf="someCondition"`, where "someCondition" is a boolean variable in your .ts file. This will be rendered if the condition evaluates as true. The second span block has `*ngIf="!someCondition"` ("if NOT some condition") which will only be rendered if the condition is false. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Hulan ! It works!     Something like this for me,   <div *ngIf="addButton">
        <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
          <a class="text-success" (click)="add()">
            <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!addButton">
        <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
          <a>
            <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

The process should be the same as the login `button`, unfortunately to give you a proper answer I need your `typescript` code.

In the meantime make sure that the loading property you are using to disable the button is set to true on your `add()` method and set to false on your save method.

Comment: Hi @CChavez, the typescript behind this html is very simple, it just includes two methods, Add() and Save() just it. as I mentioned the login button is button tag and it works properly by disable attribute, but I dont know how handle this add method by this structure that is mixed of a, span and icon.

Comment: Ah i believe I understand now, `<a>` tags can't be disabled in the same way as a button. You have some options here. You can either specify your own css styles for the `<a>` tag and change it on the click event, or add another tag and alternate between them with `ng-if` as suggested by @Ben Hulan.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ben Hulan! Final code is something like this,

```
<div *ngIf="addButton">
    <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
      <a class="text-success" (click)="add()">
        <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!addButton">
    <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
      <a>
        <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" size="2x"></mdb-icon>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
```